# Excel interop giving different output in office 2007 and office 365

Tags: excel, vba, interop

I have a VBA application developed in year of 2012 for Widows7 machine with Office 2007 which performs some operations on set of Excels and generates some set of Excels as output.

Now  I am running the same application using Visual Studio 2017 on my windows 10 machine and it gives some Range Class method exceptions.. I resolved it by placing the Activate method just above the Range class and the application generates the output.

Below was the initial code giving error "Select method of range class failed"

```
 Dim activeSheet As Worksheet = DirectCast(expression.ActiveSheet, Worksheet) 
 activeSheet.Range("A1", "DW5").Select()
```

I resolved by modifying as below.

```
Dim activeSheet As Worksheet = DirectCast(expression.ActiveSheet, Worksheet)
activeSheet.Activate() 
activeSheet.Range("A1", "DW5").Select()
```

However, the output generated in Widows7 machine with Office 2007 and the output generated in Widows10 machine with Office 365 varies for some columns for some calculations.

Is there any change in Interop version or the way of calculation in Excel? I dont know what is going wrong here!

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Well, I tried installing the Office2007 in one of the VM.. The same code gives different output in Office2007 and Office365! It is based on Slop Calculation.

Here is some code but nit sure what is does actually..

```
 With xlApplication.WorksheetFunction
      dblSlop = .Index(.LinEst(myArray), 1)
      dblCoEfficient = .Index(.LinEst(myArray, , , True), 3)(1)
      dblResult = dblSlop * dblCoEfficient
 End With
```

Comment: If you do not expose a specific such behavior, it will be very improbable to receive a piece of advice, or at least an opinion... Basically, such questions prove that something has been changed **in the application code/references etc.**, than being a matter of interoperability.  I do not say that this is your case, but for being able to separate the general discussion from something concrete, I would suggest you to edit your question and place some code examples able to prove, to show us what you generally stated... "some Range Class method exceptions" is not enough (on my taste, at least)...

Comment: Well, i even tried by generating the code from the EXE that works well in win7. But again it generates the same output I have using my code! M died finding out what's wrong here!!

Comment: The first method would always have been prone to failure, since you can't select a range on a worksheet which isn't active, and even then, *the parent workbook must have the focus*.  So if there are multiple workbooks open, your code could fail.  Perhaps if you're more specific about exactly what the problem is, someone might have some some suggestions for a fix.